# Double-space in Stack Overflow Trademark Guidance page

Tags: bug, whitespace

<sub><sub>(This is so extraordinarily minor that it hardly needs a meta post, but it *should* be fixed.)</sub></sub>

Was reading [Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange, Inc. Trademarks](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) and happened to notice two spaces in `Do feel  free to use names or logos...` on the **second item bullet point of "Design of Your Product"** (and that one only):

[image: double space in the trademarks page]

Normally, the browser would condense multiple whitespace characters into one; however, one of the spaces is a no-breaking space (`&nbsp;`), which the browser displays:

[image: extra nbsp in the HTML]

Just sayin'

---

Browser: Firefox 99.0.1
OS: macOS 12.1

Comment: Which browser(version) are you using? With latest Chrome I don't see any such issue _`" feel free to explain that your product is built on the Stack Exchange platform so people understand your product."`_

Comment: Add that and OS info to the question @undetectedSelenium.

Comment: In the latest Chrome and FF I can find `free  to` (with two spaces) @undetected.

Comment: Repro'd on Windows 10, Chrome 100. Looks like this is a source/server-side issue. // @undetectedSelenium the `&nbsp;` only exists on that specific point only, not on the other points.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yeap, it does reflects end my end as well.

Comment: This is not a minor issue in any way shape or form. This is the exact kind of content I hope to see on meta

Comment: Related: *[Stack Overflow company About page has extra space in remote work hyperlink](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417753/)*